# Azure storage failure

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, put

I'm experiencing problems with Azure PUTs. They are either extremely slow or are failing intermittently when the requests originate from servers in the US Central region. Requests from US East appear to be working ok, although a little slower than usual. Unclear if other regions originating such requests are also facing issues.

I also see the Azure Dashboard mentioning outages of  Web Apps in NA, but Storage is shown as all green. I'm assuming that the Dashboard hasn't quite caught up to the actual situation.

Comment: What do you mean by "Azure PUTs"?

Comment: Not really easy to give you an answer without any code in your question. If this is an intermittent service-related issue, then there's nothing that can be done here - not programing-related, rather service-related (and no, I don't know of any service outage).

Comment: I'm referring to the Block Blob PUTs. SO is one of the monitored forums for Azure; Hence the post.

Comment: I'm potentially experiencing the same issues.

We have no retry logic around the code for putting data into blob storage but we are getting a failure and then a success for each put.

Its very strange and started for us around 10am (utc) on 6th April 2017

Comment: Would the individual who down-voted care to explain why? SO is a forum not just for discussing code-related issues, but also for services offered by others (such as AZURE). If someone doesn't understand what AZURE PUTs mean, that's more a reflection of the ignorance of that individual and he should ask for more info. @David: yes, there was an AZURE Blob Storage outage lasting almost 24 hours on the day this question was created. Not much buzz, because the nature of the failure was unique (and was more networking related). However, the outage was acknowledged by AZURE support.

Comment: @perplexed - not sure about downvote but, as you stated, it was an outage-related issue. So, it's ultimately off-topic for StackOverflow (since StackOverflow isn't Azure Tech Support). And not cool, starting to talk about people being ignorant. I, for example, know plenty about Azure's REST APIs and I had no clue what you were specifically referring to, as you didn't give a single example. Maybe keep those types of snide, unappreciated, and inappropriate digs to yourself. Certainly keep them off of StackOverflow.

Comment: It's not off-topic. SO is used widely for monitoring/discussing issues related to Azure, AWS, Google Cloud. Recommend you respond only to questions or topics where you have something meaningful to contribute.

Comment: @perplexed, I think the question lacks information. If it's dev oriented then it would be great to add a sample code. If it's service oriented then it would be great to add more details, such as start time, charts which show degradation and that before it worked and then regressed. Right now it is not clear what to answer.
PS: I didn't down vote but I understand people who did.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with puts which surfaced through Application Insights. It took some digging to find that we were getting a 409 error.

I asked microsoft and found that CreateIfNotExists correctly returns a 409 (my error) if the container exists which i was calling each time.

Below is a link to my discussion with MS.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67652f9c-b941-4729-a3b3-21530ed9f2fb/blob-storage-is-failing-with-409-and-then-retrying-without-any-retry-code-and-succeeding?forum=windowsazuredata